# SuiteScript how to call a backend Suitelet

Tags: suitescript

I have looked at the other posts and none directly show this. I need to call a backend Suitelet from a userevent. I have created a generic backend suitelet that I need to call from multiple events, I have tried SS2 to call using https with a full qualified and a relational Suitelet URL and niether seems to work. The full qualified seems to go without error but then after the request does not enter the catch I put in place it veers off into NS library code and doesn't seem to call the Suitelet. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have included code os the call.

```
var url = 'https://debugger.sandbox.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/scriptlet.nl?script=1239&deploy=1';
var header = [];
header['Content-Type']='application/json';
var response = https.post( {
    url     : url
    , header: header
    , body  : {
        data: id
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only successfully call a Suitelet, which is available without login, from a server-side script. A Suitelet, which is not available without login, can be called from a client script as on client-side the authenticated session already exists. Perhaps a RESTlet would serve your scenario better? You can pass authentication headers when invoking the RESTlet. Otherwise, a custom module could hold the logic and be invoked from the different scripts.